# Entity Framework reset database as a PowerShell script

Tags: .net, entity-framework, powershell, batch-file, database-migration

I would like to build a bat file to run PowerShell commands which delete all migration from migrations folder and add initial and update database.

So far I have:

bat file:

```
set mypath=%cd%
PowerShell -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-File ""%mypath%\ResetMigration.ps1""' }"
```

ResetMigration.ps1

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Get-Location -Include * -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
dotnet ef database drop
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
dotnet ef database update
```

Both files are in the same folder where should I execute `dotnet ef` commands.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need a batch file? Just run your PowerShell script directly from the PowerShell prompt.

Comment: I need a batch file.

Comment: I refer the honorable gentleman to the question asked previously.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm sorry for my rude reply, but I need a bat file which I can click.

Comment: You can setup your system so that when you double click a powershell script it will execute.  But that would depend if your system admins would allow it.  I also setup my computers so that I could drag and drop files onto my Powershell script and have them process the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should be all you need in your batch file if you want to double-click on it to execute the PowerShell script (assuming the `ResetMigration.ps1` file is in the same directory as the batch file):

```
@powershell -File "%~dp0ResetMigration.ps1"
```